# Like Box plugin for my URL (not for Facebook Page URL)

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I want to have a likebox plugin for my own URL (not a Facebook Page URL)

E.g.

```
http://www.example.com/product1.html
http://www.example.com/product2.html
```

I already have opengraph meta data, and user are able to like it, but I want to have likebox kind  of plugin showing user faces...is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook says the [Facebook Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) is only for Facebook pages.  You could generate a [like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) with a show faces option for your website though.